# TSQL: Parsing strings with various characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with a file name column where various vendors named files differently.  So there is a filename with a last, first, middle name in the file with various characters separating the name.  Some have a comma + space, comma with no space, spaces between words, no spaces between words, an underscore, two underscores etc.

*What are some good ways this be extracted to the desired result?*  (It's a one-time data conversion, doesn't have to be pretty.)

What I've tried is in the sample code below, using various substring/charindex combinations

**Filename sample:** (note the commas,spaces,no-spaces,underscores, double-underscores)

[image]

**Desired Results:**

[image]

**Sample Code / Test Data (in a temp table)**

```
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#dob') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #dob

   CREATE TABLE #dob (
    FILENAME VARCHAR(MAX)
   ,StudentID INT
   ,FullName VARCHAR(500)
   ,LastName VARCHAR(500)
   ,FirstName VARCHAR(500)
   ,MiddleName VARCHAR(500)
   )

   INSERT INTO #dob
   ( FILENAME  )
   VALUES
    ('Last, First, Middle_DOB ID.pdf')
   ,('Denver, John C 11_23_1980_123456.pdf')
   ,('Denver John_11-23-1980, 1234567.pdf')
   ,('Denver,John,Clifford_ 01_22_1980_123456.pdf')
   ,('Denver, John, 11-23-1980, 1234567.pdf')
   ,('Denver, John__01_22_1980_123456.pdf')

   --This is what I tried.

   SELECT FILENAME
     ,fullname
     ,LastName
     ,FirstName
     ,MiddleName
     ,SUBSTRING(FileName,1, CHARINDEX(' ', FileName, (charindex(' ', FileName, 1))+2)) AS test1
     ,SUBSTRING(FileName,1, CHARINDEX('_', FileName, (charindex(' ', FileName, 1))+2)) AS test2
     ,SUBSTRING(FileName,1, CHARINDEX(',', FileName, (charindex(', ', FileName, 1))+1)) AS test3
     ,SUBSTRING(FileName,1, CHARINDEX(' ', FileName, (charindex('__', FileName, 1))+2)) AS test4
     ,SUBSTRING(FileName,1, CHARINDEX('__', FileName, (charindex(' ', FileName, 1))+2)) AS test5


   FROM #dob
```

Comment: This is ugly to say the least. Thankfully this is a one time thing and not an ongoing nightmare. You are going to have to make several passes at this because the format is all over the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slippery slope, but if your real data is close to the sample, consider the following.

**Example**

```
   SELECT FILENAME
         ,LastName   = Pos1
         ,FirstName  = Pos2
         ,MiddleName = case when try_convert(int,left(Pos3,1)) is null then Pos3 else '' end
   FROM #dob A
   Cross Apply ( values ( replace(
                          replace(
                          replace(
                          replace(FileName,', ',',')
                          ,' ,',',')
                          ,' ',',')
                          ,'_',',')
                        )
               ) B(CleanString)
   Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-Row](CleanString,',') C
```

**Returns**

```
FILENAME                                      LastName  FirstName   MiddleName
Last, First, Middle_DOB ID.pdf                Last      First       Middle
Denver, John C 11_23_1980_123456.pdf          Denver    John        C
Denver John_11-23-1980, 1234567.pdf           Denver    John    
Denver,John,Clifford_ 01_22_1980_123456.pdf   Denver    John        Clifford
Denver, John, 11-23-1980, 1234567.pdf         Denver    John    
Denver, John__01_22_1980_123456.pdf           Denver    John
```

**The TVF if interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-Row] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (
    Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')))
    From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml))) as A(xDim)
)
```

Comment: Thank you @JohnCappelletti!  The actual data is close to the sample data.  This worked great!  For learning purposes, I'd like to learn about what you did here.  Is the tvf xquery?  What would I need to study to understand the totality what you've done here?  Thanks again for your help, I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: @JM1 Cross Apply B will "clean the string"  this may need to be tweaked over time

Comment: @JM1 Cross Apply C will call the Table-Valued Function.  The TVF converts the string into XML and then will generate 9 columns,

Comment: @JM1 The top select just applies a little logic to to determine if there are 2 or 3 names

Comment: @JM1 Happy to help.   Full disclosure, I was a late adopter of XML.  It is worth you time,  Also, if 2016+, JSON    :)

Comment: thanks for your comments!  I'm not familiar of how to implement either.  If I wanted to learn more about XML and JSON and how to apply them in SQL, would general books on XML and JSON work, or is there SQL specific things I would need to know?  

(I'm not sure if your code is straight up XML/JSON.)  Thank you!

Comment: @JM1 This was XML not JSON.  JSON was introduced in 2016.  To learn the XML Portion I would Google "SQL Server XML Tutorial" or start with https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2889/basic-sql-server-xml-querying/

Comment: you have been such a great help!  I hope you have a great day and thank you!

Comment: @JM1 Thanks for the grin  :)

Comment: Hi John, nice answer, as always! I liked the *"slippery slope"*. As a non-english speaker this sounds very slick ;-)

Comment: @Shnugo I forget English is your 2nd(?) language.  On the CEFR Proficiency Scale , I would guess that you are a C1 / C2.     My daughter (currently living in Japan) is fluent in Italian, Chinese, Japanese and Spanish.  It is fascinating to watch her speak.  She adopts a different persona with each language. Like "slippery slope", she keeps a collection of idioms for each language.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I tried using patindex, See if this helps

```
SELECT FILENAME
    ,fullname
    ,LastName
    ,FirstName
    ,MiddleName
    ,ISNULL(LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)-1),'')
    +' '
    +ISNULL(LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')),PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))-1),'')
    +' '
    +ISNULL(IIF(PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')),PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')))))>1
    ,IIF(PATINDEX('%[a-z]%',LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')),PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')))),PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')),PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')))))),1))=1,
    LEFT(LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')),PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')))),PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')),PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')))))-1)
    ,NULL)
    ,NULL),'') FULLNAME
    ,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)-1) LASTNAME
    ,LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')),PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))-1) FIRSTNAME
    ,IIF(PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')),PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')))))>1
    ,IIF(PATINDEX('%[a-z]%',LEFT(LEFT(LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')),PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')))),PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')),PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')))))),1))=1,
    LEFT(LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')),PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')))),PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LEFT(LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')),PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)+PATINDEX('%[, _]%',LTRIM(REPLACE(FILENAME,LEFT(FILENAME,PATINDEX('%[, _]%',FILENAME)),'')))),'')))))-1)
    ,NULL)
    ,NULL) MIDDLENAME
FROM #dob
```

Comment: thank you for your time, this does output as requested.